# Can't seem to display data from mongolab using node.js

Tags: node.js, mlab

i'm been trying to display just a simple data from mongolab to nodejs and it displays nothing for some reason.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect("mongodb://db-user:pass@ds049084.mongolab.com:49084/mydb");
mongoose.model('collection',{ name:String });

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  mongoose.model('collection').find({},function(err,docs){
     res.send(docs);
  });
});
```

I've already saved a name data in the document of the collection in mongolab, the only it shows when i run the debug script
    debug=mynode:* npm start is []

does anybody know why is that? thank you.

Comment: something that's been bugging me, if i add the document at mongolab manually, and i use this code above to connect to the collection, will it load the data from the collection or I have to add it from node to mongolab to work?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!, man..the problem is the way i named the collections at mongolab. I was missing the "s" at the end of collection. Once i deleted the collection and created another but this time the "s" at the end, then it worked.

e.g.
Naming a collection 'Car' will not work but naming it 'cars' will work somehow

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet because of my rep...
But to elaborate.. The reason why you need the "s" at the end is because when you do:

```
mongoose.model('<the schema you want to map to in your db>',<yourschema>);
```

"Mongoose automatically looks for the plural version of your model name" in your db.. as it says in the Mongoose documentation.. hence if you type myDbSchema it would look for myDbSchemas (Note the "s") and so thats why in your mongolabs Db the schema would need the extra "s"... confused me for a bit to but I hope this can help someone! :) as this post did help me too.

FYI Mongoose documentation: [Mongoose Models Doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)